# adLDAP -- How to retrieve user's Group Membership?

Tags: php, ldap, adldap

I'm new to LDAP concepts and also now starting with [adLDAP](http://adldap.sourceforge.net) for PHP. Now everything is ok upto authentication.

Then how can i get the "**Group Membership**" (the Group Name where the member is existing) of a user after logged in, by knowing "only" the `username` and `password` ?

Comment: Please do not cross post

Comment: My bad. I saw your three posts, they looked similar. Edit your question to unlock it, I will undo my downvote. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Please what??? Non of my posts are duplicated. Please read the different topics carefully.

Comment: You are right, none of your posts are duplicated. It was my mistake, I will read all the topics carefully. I will undo the -1. But since it has been more than a few hours since the vote was cast, I cannot change it unless you edit your question. +No need to add `adlap` to the title, that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

Oh i got it now! :D

```
$result = $adldap->user()->groups("username");
print_r($result);
```